# Can't apt-get install libssl-dev

Tags: apt

Here is what I get when I try to `apt-get install libssl-dev`:

```
root@raspi:/home/pi/cfengine-3.7.0a1.283240b# apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev libssl-doc
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,704 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,219 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libssl-dev armhf 1.0.1e-2+rpi1
  404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1e-2+rpi1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

No amount of updating or fix-missing will work. I have installed several other packages - but how can I get this one?

Comment: You may have just run into unfortunate coincidence that the mirror you hit hadn't been synched after an `openssl-dev` update.  Can you confirm whether running `sudo apt-get update` now fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

On "Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)" you need to first do an "upgrade". So the following should work.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

"Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1e-2+rpi1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found"

Thats not the current version (by a long way), so it sounds like your package lists are out of date. Normally "apt-get update" would be used to update them.

You say "no ammount of updating helped" but you don't post the actual output from apt-get update so it's rather difficult to say exactly why it's not working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I have been 3 days working over my email sending routines...
I am using Lazarus 1.6 with Freepascal 3.0... and Raspbian Stretch
I am using xmailer as it has an easy component to send emails.
To make it work I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a hack solution but it's what I'd do if I were in this situation.

[That directory](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/) contains three `libssl-dev` packages, only one of them is for 1.0.1e, so that should be the one you want.

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u17_armhf.deb
```

You can then install it manually:

```
sudo dpkg -i openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u17_armhf.deb
```

I'm not sure whether `dpkg` cares about dependencies, but the `INFO` file inside the package only lists two, a corresponding `libssl` and `zlib1g-dev`.

**Before you do that,** if you have not, I would do a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` and retry `apt-get install libssl-dev`.  Also note that openSSL 1.0.1e is susceptible to [the Heartbleed bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed), if this is significant to what you are building you may want to upgrade somehow (there's a 1.0.1k in that directory too, which might be for jessie).

Comment: Upstream 1.0.1e is susceptible to heartbleed but Debian 1.0.1e-2+deb7u17 and raspbian 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u17 (which is basically the same, just with the version number changed for version ordering reasons) have the issue patched.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0/trusty libssl-dev/trusty openssl/trusty

from:[Unable to install libssl1.0.0:i386 due to “unmet dependencies”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462094/unable-to-install-libssl1-0-0i386-due-to-unmet-dependencies/462471#462471)

Answer (score 0):

I keep facing with issue of **Hash Sum mismatch** with **apt-get update** with the default sources list.

By changing to another raspbian mirror which is close to where I am, I can finally install the libssl-dev.

[Raspbian mirrors](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors)